# how to deploy wso2 products in aws beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to deploy wso2 products in aws using beanstalk.

Theoretically it should be possible by following the instructions for deploying in webapp mode.

http://wso2.org/project/carbon/3.2.2/docs/admin_guide.html#webappmode

Has anyone managed to achieve this?
What steps were required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the document [1] you shared should work.

However, unless you really have a requirement, it is not that encouraged to run WSO2 Products in web app mode. This is because the Web app container will limit the WSO2 products, where WSO2 Products can function independently in stand-alone mode. Running WSO2 stand-alone over the EC2 might be more appropriate.

[1] http://wso2.org/project/carbon/3.2.2/docs/admin_guide.html#webappmode

Comment: It would be good if there was a warning on the wiki page to inform that running in webapp mode is not encouraged, and why it is not encouraged.