# can wso2 carbon 4.1 run as a web app (war)?

Tags: wso2

I'm limited to what applications I can deploy in my environment, however, standard WAR files are usually not a problem.

Can carbon 4.1.0 run as a web app?

This [link](http://wso2.org/project/carbon/3.2.2/docs/admin_guide.html#webappmode) describes how it can be done for carbon 3.2.2.  Are these steps still valid for 4.1.0?

According to the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566545/how-to-deploy-wso2-products-in-aws-beanstalk) some functionality is limited in webapp mode for 3.2.2.  What functionality is limited if 4.1.0 is deployed in webapp mode?

**EDIT:**

A `webapp-mode` folder is available in `$CARBON_HOME`

```
C:\Users\snowc\Desktop\wso2carbon-4.1.0>type webapp-mode\README.txt
Running WSO2 Carbon in Webapp mode
-------------------------------------

Standalone mode is the recommended way of running All WSO2 Carbon products. However you have the
option of running WSO2 Carbon products in Webapp mode (hosted as a web-app in an application
server).

1. The 'WEB-INF' directory contains the webapp archive
2. The 'bundles' directory contains the additional jars that needs, during the web-app mode
   deployment.

Please refer the WSO2 Carbon documentation for step-by-step guide on web-app mode deployment of the
product.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can carbon 4.1.0 run as a web app?"

No, we stopped supporting webapp deployment in later 4.x.x carbon versions

Comment: That is a shame!!  I have updated my question with the contents of the `webapp-mode\README.txt`  I guess that folder should be removed from carbon.

Comment: will Carbon 4.1.0 run as a web app even if not officially supported by WSO2?

Comment: I am trying to run WSO2 API Manager as a web app and no success. Do you have any info regarding? or from Carbon 4.1.0 is not working at all?