# can wso2ues 1.0 (carbon server) run as a web app?

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to run WSO2UES (Carbon) as a web application in Apache Tomcat. I've followed the procedure discussed at http://pradeepfernando.blogspot.com/2012/09/running-wso2-carbon-as-web-app-apache.html.

I've added the web application folders into Tomcat webapps folder, configured HTTPS listener of Tomcat. Server logs show that application is successfully deployed and OSGI console is started. When I try to connect to application from https://myIp.com:8443/crbn/carbon, I get a 404 error. There are no exceptions in server logs.

Tomcat error screen contains reference to BridgeServlet: /crbn/carbon, so I know that request is correctly forwarded to BridgeServlet. I guess BridgeServlet can not locate and run the application from OSGI bundles. But I do not have any idea about why and how I can fix it.

How can I diagnose the problem, or is there any available source of information for the correct procedure?

Note: I'm using WSO2UES 1.0, Apache Tomcat 7.0.40. I've tried Java versions 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 UES 1.0 is based on carbon 4.1.0. AFAIK they are not officially support on  web app mode.

[can wso2 carbon 4.1 run as a web app (war)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959326/can-wso2-carbon-4-1-run-as-a-web-app-war)

previous architecture handled using a concept called “Bridge Servlet”, so if you want to run it as previous you have to do some customized work.

here is a article on architecture difference on carbon latest.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/understanding-wso2-carbon-architecture/